# Can we limit the response size from Google Geocoding API?

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I have the atm locator feature which I am running on Mobile, I want to display max 10 records on my search page.

On placing the request can we limit the size of response? Is it possible to retrieve maximum 10 records for any search crieteria?

**I want to limit the response size to reduce the result retrieval time. Current retrieval time is more and it's a performance issue for mobile**

I have seen the Google Geocoding API and no request parameter fulfilling my requirement. Am I missing anything, any pointers will be great.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this. And latency has much more to do with the network and the time to get the response than the size of the response itself.